# How to manage tickets event?

Tags: 7

I have to handle tickets request. Let me explain (sorry for my english):

On the site, each authenticated user create a club (Master Club) and members (Master Members). Master Club and Master Members are two content types.

Each club administrator (authenticated user) must be able to send a request for tickets event and indicate the tickets number by listing the name, address and other data of the shareholders chooses from its list.

The structure is similar TICKET module: Site administrator create a content type EVENT. For each EVENT specify the sector( SECTOR_A, SECTOR_B,.....) and for each SECTOR how many tickets want.

scenario: Let's say you require 3 tickets for SECTOR_A and 2 tickets for SECTOR_B:

This request must be sent to the site administrator which can confirm this request or notify club administrator that instead of 5 tickets they can take only 2 tickets for SECTOR_A and 1 tickets for SECTOR_B..

The club administrator receives this notification and can accept the site administrator's request indicating the members(from its membership list) who want to assign these 3 tickets or refuse.

How set it ?

Comment: Seems like you did look at the Ticket module, so what's wrong or missing in that module to address your question? BTW: questions like "Is there a module for it" are usually not allowed on this site ...

Comment: I'm not unable to set it for my scenario....I'm trying to do it...

Comment: BTW:...and sorry for questions...i didn't know.

Comment: no need for "sorry", I suggest you just delete your last line of your question ...

Comment: And finally do you found an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately still no. I'm looking the solution...

Answer (score 2):

The [Ticket](https://www.drupal.org/project/ticket) module is a good point to start.

> Ticket is a module that provides ticketing and registration for events
>   (and more abstractly, entities). Events may have multiple ticket
>   types, each with a unique set of requirements and registration fields.

Comment: It's true, but i don't know how to set it for my scenario. I'm trying to do it...

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: @Prof I never has used this module.